# Restricting user login by IP address

Tags: htaccess, security, permissions, ip

I have a website that is login required in order for users to view the website.
I have set up one user for all internal members to use to view the website, however i want to limit just that user to our specific IP address.

I can see you can limit access site-wide to an IP address via htaccess, but i only need to implement it for one user, so they can only view the website from our IP address.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean to "Exit login for everyone except for specific IP addresses?"

Comment: @SamuelElh The website forces a login in order to view the front-end (similar to a intranet sort of thing). But i want to be able to limit one specific user to logging in, unless they are at a specific IP address.

So something like: For User ID 1, if IP Address = {{IP Address here}}, then allow login. If not, then dont allow login

Comment: Try smth like this http://pastebin.com/6MYgCpLF, there's a custom hook that runs after user login which you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### IP address validation during authentication - for a selected user only

Here's a way to hook into the `authenticate` filter and validate the IP address for a given user during authentication.

The user can see the *invalid IP address* error like shown here:

[image: invalid IP address]

```
/**
 * Validate IP Address During Authentication - For A Given User 
 */
add_filter( 'authenticate', function( $user )
{
    // Adjust to your needs:
    $allowed_user_ip        = '127.0.0.1';
    $ip_restricted_user_id  = 1;

    // Current user's IP address
    $current_user_ip = isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : null;

    // Nothing to do for valid IP address
    if( $current_user_ip === $allowed_user_ip )
        return $user;

    // Nothing to do for users that are not IP restricted 
    if( 
           $user instanceof \WP_User 
        && $user->ID > 0
        && $ip_restricted_user_id != $user->ID
    )   
        return $user;

    // Add an 'Invalid IP address' error
    if( is_wp_error( $user ) )
        $user->add( 
            'invalid_ip', 
            sprintf(
            '<strong>%s</strong>: %s',
            esc_html__( 'ERROR', 'mydomain' ),
            esc_html__( 'IP address is invalid.', 'mydomain' )
        )
    ); 
    // Create a new 'Invalid IP address' error
    else
        $user = new WP_Error(
            'invalid_ip', 
            sprintf(
                '<strong>%s</strong>: %s',
                esc_html__( 'ERROR', 'mydomain' ),
                esc_html__( 'IP address is invalid.', 'mydomain' )
            )
        ); 

    return $user;
}, 100 );
```

Here we use the priority of 100 because of these default callbacks:

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password',  20, 3 );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_email_password',     20, 3 );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_spam_check',         99    );
```

It should be possible to extend this to handle a group of users or a given user role.

Comment: @Futwill if the answer from birgire did answer your question please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer.